# Playing Hacknet without Unix knowledge possible?

Tags: hacknet

I'm really interested in playing Hacknet but my problem is that I don't have any Unix command knowledge. And as the game is based on Unix commands I'm not quite sure whether I should buy it, because I don't want to end up frustated searching for solutions. Is there enough "tutorial" so that someone without Unix knowledge can play it or not?

(*sidenote: I'm a programming apprentice that has been working with Java, so I have general knowledge of programming*)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. The tutorial will take you through everything you need to know, and the commands are not sufficiently complex to form anything even approaching the rich language that bash and the like can provide. Experienced shell users  might enjoy seeing some of the names carry over (`nmap`, `cat`, ...), but it's nothing like the real thing. Indeed, I found it a bit frustrating that I couldn't use most of the features of my real command line in the game.

If you're interested in learning how to drive a real Unix shell, http://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/ is a fun place to start.

Comment: Thank you very much for all this information! Now I'm definately trying it out (:

Comment: BTW: Got the game and began playing it a little. Seems quite interesting

Comment: And the `help` command will always be there when you forget something.

Comment: If it turns out you love the bash shell after your practice, you can even use it to solve programming puzzles at codingame.com or in http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/